# Erasing and modifying last/specific lines of file in python

Tags: python, file

For example i have this file with the following text:

```
Hello
One
two
Goodbye
```

And I want to add "three" between "two" and "Goodbye"

How i can do this?

Comment: Nothing shows up in Google for 'Python modify text files'?

Comment: Tried anything? opening file? reading lines? an attempt to change?

Comment: @MuhammadAhmad Clearly not.

Comment: Should have specified :
Writing on the file overwrites what was previously written
Using append just adds text at the end of the file

Answer (score -1):

First of all you should read the file content: (assuming your file is in the same folder as your .py file)

```
name = "YOUR FILE NAME" # including extension, such as "myfile.txt"

data = []
filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(name)) 
if os.path.exists(filename):
    with open(filename) as fin:
        for entry in fin.readlines():
            data.append(entry.rstrip())
```

After you should insert the other element in the data array (in this case on the index 3)

```
data.insert(3, "three")
```

As last point, just save the file with this new information:

```
with open(filename, 'w') as fout:
    for entry in data:
        fout.write(entry + '\n')
```